# BeautifulSoup XML parsing not working

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, urllib2, lxml

I'm trying to parse an XML page with `BeautifulSoup` and for some reason it's not able to find the XML parser. I don't think it's a path issue as I've used `lxml` to parse pages in the past, just not XML. Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import *
import urllib2
import lxml
from lxml import *


BASE_URL = "http://auctionresults.fcc.gov/Auction_66/Results/xml/round/66_115_database_round.xml"

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'http://myProxy.com})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"xml") 

print soup
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but all the XML parsing with BS questions I found on here were around bs3 and I'm using bs4 which uses a different method for parsing XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `lxml` installed, just call that as `BeautifulSoup`'s parser instead, like below.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq

url = "http://auctionresults.fcc.gov/Auction_66/Results/xml/round/66_115_database_round.xml"
r = rq.get(url)

soup = bsoup(r.content, "lxml")
print soup
```

**Result:**

```
<html><body><dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nonamespaceschemalocation="66_database.xsd"><all_bids>
<auction_id>66</auction_id>
<auction_description>Advanced Wireless Services</auction_description>
... really long list follows...
[Finished in 34.9s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: It must be a path issue, because it works in iPython but not in Eclipse PyDev. I'll sort it out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That's kind of weird. Glad to know you found the root of the problem, though. In any case, the above answer works well as a workaround. :)